# Electronic Image Stabilization in drones

Tags: video

I am exploring on various Electronic Image Stabilization algorithms for camera on drones.
Got few links to understand what EIS is all about:

1. [AUTOMATIC TARGET DETECTION AND TRACKING IN UAV IMAGERY](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/%7Emennatul/?p=13)
2. [UAV Payload & Equipment Features](https://octopus.uavfactory.com/uav-payload-equipment-features)

Any inputs to get started with development would be appreciated (helpful if links/videos/algorithm/books).

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you trying to develop your own EIS software, implement an existing software into your drone, or something else?

Comment: Hi @Jacob I am looking to Implement own EIS algorithm or add any existing EIS algorithm to my drone.